# Can I roll back a procedure execution?

Tags: t-sql

Can I roll back an executed procedure in a transaction?

```
Begin Transaction

Exec dbo.InsertIntoCustomerTable

Rollback Transaction
```

Is this valid?

Comment: What are the results when you try it?  Which db is being used?

Comment: Why don't you check it yourself? It's a really simple test after all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can.

It is very useful to test procedure on production for any errors or model problems. The best way is to put `TRY .... CATCH` block and raport errors. That's great way to test procedure.